# Understanding air compressor CFM, PSI

Tags: compressors

I need some help in choosing the right air compressor for my airtable and understanding how CFM and PSI can be used to calculate the system. I read standard google links, pressure drop per linear ft, etc. These aren't helpful in designing the system. Let me briefly describe the setup; small air compressor feeds N flexible lines to individual N table holes. Each hole is supposed to have [x] force to provide a tiny lift force. CFM is a flow measure volume/time. I started converting CFM into linear velocity by dividing by tube size. I didn't need PSI, that was odd.

Is there a better way to set up an equation for my problem using compressor CMF/PSI to lift force on a table?

Comment: What is the compressor used for? I think the pressure is more relevant than the velocity in general terms.

Comment: it pumps air to individual holes drilled in the table top.